# Adding a check constraint to a name in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to add a check constraint to my table which checks that the `FNAME` and the `LNAME` are not empty. I have implemented something like this:

```
 ALTER TABLE Person
 ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_NOTEMPTYNAME CHECK (LEN(Fname, LName) > 0);
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Does the length of both `Fname` **and** `LName` need to be longer than 0, or is it that either `Fname` **or** `LName` need to be longer than 0?

Comment: Both Fname and Lname

Answer (score 2):

You need two separate `LEN()` function :

```
 ALTER TABLE Person
     ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_NOTEMPTYNAME CHECK (LEN(Fname) > 0 AND LEN(LName) > 0);
```

However, you can also do :

```
 ALTER TABLE Person
         ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_NOTEMPTYNAME CHECK ( Fname <> '' AND LName <>  '' );
```